# If the equation $3x+5y=k$ has exactly $4$ positive integral solutions and $k$ is the largest number for which this is possible, then what is $k$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, contest-math

> If the equation $$3x+5y=k$$ has exactly $4$ positive integral solutions and $k$ is the largest number for which this is possible, what is the value of $k$?

I can't wrap my head around the fact that why the values of $y$ will be limited to only $1$,$2$ and $3$. Why can not we go beyond that?

Comment: Do you mean positive *integer* solutions?

Comment: Have you tried drawing a picture?  What does the graph look like?

Comment: @Student1058 Yes, positive integral solutions as mentioned in the Question STEM.

Answer (score 1):

$ax+by=c$ if $a,b,c,x,y$ are positive integers and $gcd(a,b)=1$, then the number of positive integer pairs are given by $N+1$ if integer part of $c/(ab)$ is $N$ and the remainder ($r$) when $c$ is divided by $(ab)$ has a solution for $r=ax_0+by_0$ where $x_0,y_0$ are positive integers.

So if $3x+5y=59$, then $N=3$ and $r=14$, check that $14=3x+5y$ has asolution $(3,1)$.
So the starting eqn will have 4 solutions.

But if $k=60$, the given equation will have $60/15=4$ number of solution and no more becaues $3x+5y=0$ cannot have solution as positive integer pair, as $0$ is not a positive integer.

Finally, $k_{max}=60$.

Comment: The answer is kmax= 75. Sorry.

Comment: Yes, you are right.